# Color Format not appearing using ireport 4.8 or ireport 4.7 while exporting to excel

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a serious problem with ireport that i am setting backcolor for text as RGB value of [231,233,219] and making opaque property to true when i am previewing using excel i am able to view same color but after saving the report as pdf or exporting to pdf by code the color RGB value changed to [255,255,204].

Answer (score 0):

ireport using base color scheme for generating excel reports. But if we want to use some advance color scheme than we should follow the following procedure

1. Get jxl 2.6 jar
2. get itext 2.1.7.jar
3. user JExcelApiExporter for developing excel report and set JExcelApiExporterParameter.CREATE_CUSTOM_PALETTE to true